# In simple python, how to generate a zero-list of size n with x ones and y negative ones placed in it randomly?

Tags: python-3.x, list, random

Something like this,

```py
def T(x, y, n=7):
  # implement this
  pass
```

For example, `T(3, 2) = [1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1]` and `T(2, 2) = [1, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0]`.

I'd like the solution to be just in vanilla python.

Comment: @Brian Tompsett, What details are missing? Someone already answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do something like this-

```py
import random

def T(x, y, n=7):
    return random.sample([1]*x + [-1]*y + [0]*(n-x-y), n)
```

To try a test case you could simply run this piece of code-

```py
print(T(3, 2))
```

Comment: What about `print(T(4,4))` ?

Comment: @gboffi x + y has to be less than or equal to n.

Comment: As told by @scribe x + y <= n should be followed, I would just ask you to read the question again if you didn't quite follow me so as to why this should hold true and try by hand for (4, 4, 7)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def T(x, y, n=7):
    number_list = []
    choices = [-1, 0, 1]

    # fill the list until its length is < n
    while len(number_list) < n:
        # get a random number among -1, 0 and 1
        random_number = random.choice(choices)

        # fill the list
        number_list.append(random_number)

    return number_list

print(T(3, 2))
print(T(2, 2))
```